# query about avg's max

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, average

I have this query: Find the branch and branche's city with the biggest avg amounts for product 'beta600' between 2010-2014.
I execute this code but I get no results. It takes about 10 min to execute and it gives null. Can u help?

```
SELECT DISTINCT branch_code,branch_city, AVG(trn_amount)) AS max_avg
FROM branches,transactions,products,accounts
WHERE branches.branch_code = accounts.branch_code AND 
products.product_code = accounts.product_code AND 
accounts.account_id = transactions.account_id AND 
product_name = 'Beta600' AND
trn_date > '31/12/2009' AND trn_date < '1/1/2015'
GROUP BY branch_code,branch_city
ORDER BY max_avg
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: syntax error: extra `)` in in `AVG()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems reasonable, but the query could use some work.  Here are recommendations:

- Use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always`use explicit`JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.
- Use standard date formats -- YYYY-MM-DD.

The resulting query:

```
SELECT b.branch_code, b.branch_city, AVG(t.trn_amount)) AS max_avg
FROM branches b JOIN
     accounts a
     ON b.branch_code = a.branch_code JOIN
     transactions t
     ON a.account_id = t.account_id JOIN
     products p
     ON p.product_code = a.product_code
WHERE p.product_name = 'beta600' AND
      t.trn_date > '2009-12-31' AND t.trn_date < '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY branch_code, branch_city
ORDER BY max_avg
LIMIT 1;
```

If your query is returning no results, then the `WHERE` clause is filtering everything out.  Perhaps the date format or casing of the product name is causing the problem.